# Reset value of a label into a function

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter, label, reset

I want to reset a label into a function, at the beginning I have done this :

```
Label3 = Label(Mafenetre)
Label3.pack(side = TOP, pady = 5)
```

and call into my function (when clicking a button) :

```
def main() :  
    Label3.config(text='')
    Label3 = Label(Mafenetre, text = '654')
    Label3.pack()
```

But I had this error : 
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'Label3' referenced before assignement

So I tried this :

```
def main() :   
    if not Label3 : 
        Label3 = Label(Mafenetre)
        Label3.pack(side = TOP, pady = 5)

    Label3.config(text='')
    Label3 = Label(Mafenetre, text = '654')
    Label3.pack()
```

but I still have the same problem and I don't understand why because if the variable is not defined, it should be created.
What I am doing wrong? Is it the good method?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to re-create the Label instance inside the function because it already exists. When you do that, `Label3` is now local to that function, so accessing `config` is going to throw an error because `Label3` doesn't exist yet--inside that function. Just change main to this:

```
def main() :  
    Label3.config(text='654')
```

And then it should work.